# При генерации Java проекта из собственного архетипа не создаётся файл проекта и не используется artifactId в имени пакета

Tags: java, maven, archetype

Имеется проект Maven архетипа для генерации проектов Java, который был создан с помощью [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype@1.4](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-archetype). Проблема в том, что при генерации проекта с помощью созданного архетипа файловая структура создаётся, но файл `.project` в корне созданного проекта отсутствует. Помимо этого в переменной `$package`, которая должна содержать имя пакета состоящее из комбинации `groupId` и `artifactId` указанных при генерации, отсутствует `artifactId`, также и в созданной файловой структуре отсутствует директория соотносящаяся с `artifactId`.
Другими словами при генерации проекта следующим образом:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=io.github.xelanimed \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=java11-junit5 \
-DarchetypeVersion=0.0.1 \
-DgroupId=com.example \
-DartifactId=sandbox-test
```

сгенерированным именем пакета в файле `App.java` находящемуся в директории `src/main/java/com/example` является `com.example`, т.е. вместо ожидаемого файла
`src/main/java/com/example/sandbox_test/App.java` мы получаем
`src/main/java/com/example/App.java`

Устанавливал в локальный репозиторий архетип и так: `mvn clean install archetype:update-local-catalog` и так `mvn clean install` с "ручным" удалением старого артефакта.

Переломал уже все бубны, но не могу понять в чём проблема и что я делаю неправильно?

---

#### Использованные руководства, ресурсы, ссылки по теме

- [Guide to Creating Archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)
- [Guide to Maven Archetype by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-archetype)
- [How to create custom maven archetypes?](https://medium.com/@panduka.karunasena/how-to-create-custom-maven-archetypes-d6a98fc64cb6)
- [ArchetypeDescriptor](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html)

---

##### Структура проекта архетипа

```
java11-junit5/
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   └── resources/
│   │       ├── archetype-resources/
│   │       │   ├── src/
│   │       │   │   ├── main/
│   │       │   │   │   ├── java/
│   │       │   │   │   │   └── App.java
│   │       │   │   │   └── resources/
│   │       │   │   │       ├── filterable/
│   │       │   │   │       │   └── README.md
│   │       │   │   │       └── logback-test.xml
│   │       │   │   └── test/
│   │       │   │       ├── java/
│   │       │   │       │   ├── AppTest.java
│   │       │   │       │   └── TestBase.java
│   │       │   │       └── resources
│   │       │   ├── .gitignore
│   │       │   ├── pom.xml
│   │       │   └── README.md
│   │       └── META-INF/
│   │           └── maven/
│   │               └── archetype-metadata.xml
│   └── test/
│       └── resources/
│           └── projects/
│               └── it-basic/
│                   ├── archetype.properties
│                   └── goal.txt
├── target
├── .project
├── pom.xml
└── README.md
```

---

#### Исходники

##### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.xelanimed</groupId>
    <artifactId>java11-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>

    <name>Archetype - java11-junit5</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
                <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

##### .project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>java11-junit5</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

##### src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
    name="java11-junit5">

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="groupId" />
        <requiredProperty key="artifactId" />
        <requiredProperty key="version">
          <defaultValue>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
      <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false">
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false">
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

##### src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/App.java

```java
package $package;

public class App
{
    /**
     * Using example:
     * {@snippet file="AppTest.java" region="main"}
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "args: " + java.util.Arrays.toString( args ) );
    }
}
```

##### src/main/java/com/example/App.java

```java
package com.example;

public class App
{
    /**
     * Using example:
     * {@snippet file="AppTest.java" region="main"}
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "args: " + java.util.Arrays.toString( args ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё ниже описанное выполнялось в IDE Eclipse...

На счёт отсутствующего файла `.project`...
При генерации проекта из консоли (`mvn archetype:generate...`) создаётся только структура проекта без файла `.project`. Может быть отсутствует какой-либо необходимый файл или ключ конфигурации, но сейчас решается самостоятельным импортом проекта. Для этого нужно выбрать меню `File->Import...`, в появившемся мастере выбрать `General->Projects from Folder or Archive` и на следующем шаге выбрать корневую директорию сгенерированного проекта.
При генерации проекта с помощью мастера (`File->New->Maven project`) проект создаётся, но требует интерактивного режима из-за использования обязательного свойства `package` (см.ниже).

На счёт содержимого заполнителя/переменной Velocity `$package`...
Оказывается, что значение `groupId` является значением по умолчанию и для заполнителя `$package`. В документации или каких-то других источниках не нашёл информацию о доступных заполнителях, но в данном случае решил так:

##### src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
    name="${artifactId}">

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="version">
          <defaultValue>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="package">
          <defaultValue>${groupId}.${artifactId.replaceAll("-", "_")}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
      <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false">
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false">
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

Здесь мы добавляем обязательное свойство `package` и устанавливаем ему значение по умолчанию, попутно заменяя в идентификаторе артефакта дефисы на нижнее подчёркивание.

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Как хранятся метаданные об архетипе?](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html)
- [Исходники на GitHub](https://github.com/XelaNimed/archetype-java11-junit5)
- [архетип на Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.xelanimed/java11-junit5)